# django - how can I write data to an external Mongo database?

Tags: django, mongodb

I have a Django app that is using PostgreSQL.  Everything is fine.  However, I have a situation in which it would be very convenient for my Django app to update the Mongo database of an entirely different app that is running a different server, etc.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what Django is or how you are talking to Postgress, but ultimately, it boils down to using  one of the MongoDB supported language drivers in order to communicate with MongoDB.  The programming languages supported are here: [drivers](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/)

Answer (score 1):

One option to consider is [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/), an Object-Document Mapper (ODM) that implements a declarative API similar to Django. You can then use Django's support for multiple databases to route requests appropriately.

See:

- [Django Support in MongoEngine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/django.html)
- [Django documentation: Multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/)